# How to sample without replacement using c++ uniform_int_distribution

Tags: c++, random

I want to use the uniform_int_distribution in the c++ random library. However, it only does the sampling with replacement, as in the example below. How can I sample without replacement?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,4);

  for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    std::cout << distribution(generator) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "with replacement"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `std::shuffle` on, say, a `std::array<int>` or a `std::vector<int>`, initialised to `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.

Then read back the container contents in order.

This will have better statistical properties than drawing a random number and accepting it only if it hasn't been drawn before.

Reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: I would use `std::shuffle` instead.

Comment: That's a good point: better to use the new function when using C++11.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean, better statistical properties? Suppose you require only two draws without replacement from a large vector. The shuffle algorithm will be of linear complexity in the size of the vector, whereas the alternative suggestion (drawing and rejecting if already drawn) would be O(1).

Comment: @quant_dev in that sense the statistical properties of both algorithms will be the same...

Answer (score 9):

As of c++17, there is now a standard library function which does exactly this. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string in = "abcdefgh", out;
    std::sample(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
                5, std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
    std::cout << "five random letters out of " << in << " : " << out << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sample `N` uniformly distributed integers without replacement from the range `[low, high)`, you can write this:

```
std::vector<int> array(N);   // or reserve space for N elements up front
 
auto gen = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()};
    
std::ranges::sample(std::views::iota(low, high), 
                    array.begin(),
                    N, 
                    gen);

std::ranges::shuffle(array, gen);  // only if you want the samples in random order
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aGvjGG).

This is similar to [Philip M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56062638/8372853), but from C++20 the input range can be generated lazily.